# Installing devtools package in R

Tags: r, devtools

Trying to install devtools package is resulting in a segmentation error? Can any one help me what i might be doing wrong or a possible solution to the issue ? Also while loading the devtools it throws an error.

```
 install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘/Users/srao1/Library/R/3.3/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/src/contrib/devtools_1.12.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 466618 bytes (455 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 455 KB

* installing *source* package ‘devtools’ ...
** package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c devtools.c -o devtools.o
gcc -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o devtools.so devtools.o -L/usr/local/lib/R/lib -lR -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Users/srao1/Library/R/3.3/library/devtools/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
 4: asNamespace(ns)
 5: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
 6: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
 7: asNamespace(ns)
 8: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
 9: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc, keep.source, partial = TRUE)
10: withCallingHandlers(expr, packageStartupMessage = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
11: suppressPackageStartupMessages(loadNamespace(package, lib.loc,     keep.source, partial = TRUE))
12: code2LazyLoadDB(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source,     compress = compress)
13: makeLazyLoading(pkg_name, lib, keep.source = keep.source)
14: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
15: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
16: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
17: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
18: try({    suppressPackageStartupMessages(.getRequiredPackages(quietly = TRUE))    makeLazyLoading(pkg_name, lib, keep.source = keep.source)})
19: do_install_source(pkg_name, instdir, pkg, desc)
20: do_install(pkg)
21: tools:::.install_packages()
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
/usr/local/lib/R/bin/INSTALL: line 34: 75279 Done                    echo 'tools:::.install_packages()'
     75280 Segmentation fault: 11  | R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES= LC_COLLATE=C "${R_HOME}/bin/R" $myArgs --slave --args ${args}
```

My Session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: Complete lack of details but a FAQ:  use more ram (you are likely on a minimal cloud instance) or use a _binary_ of devtools.  They exist for Linux distros too.

Comment: What R version? What OS? Maybe share the output of `sessionInfo()`. There's not a lot to go on here.

Comment: I have added the session info @MrFlick

Comment: I tried to install from binary  but it's failing too.

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473340/r-startup-taking-all-my-memory-r

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I don't have any .Rdata files in my current working directory

Comment: updating all the packages in R has helped to resolve the issue