# R startup taking all my memory [r]

Tags: r, memory

So, R is taking all my memory when I try to start it, freezing my computer. After several minutes it will open and run normally, but it is still very annoying.

-Pertinent information:
I have tried reinstalling and rebooting already. 
I'm not trying to load any workspace when opening, when it finally opens, ls() gives me character(0). 
I'm not using R studio. 
The problem has been going on for about a week already and I haven't been doing anything I wasn't doing before. 
Nothing similar happens to any other software I'm using.

Question:
Is anyone having similar problems and/or have any leads on how can I fix this? I searched the forums but could not find anything similar.

Here are my specifications:

- R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"
- macOS Sierra 10.12.2
- Memory: 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Processor: 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is R directly installed on your MacBook or on some cloud drive?

Comment: It is installed on my macbook.

Comment: When `R` does start up, are there any data in the environment?  You can check by typing `ls()`?

Comment: Also check for a file `.Rprofile` in your home directory (i.e. run `ls ~/.Rprofile` in the Terminal application)

Comment: ls() returns character(0) and ls ~/.Rprofile returns ls: /Users/gabriel/.Rprofile: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! There was an .Rapp.history file hidden in my home directory. Just had to show hidden files and delete that.

Thanks to all who have answered.

Answer (score 1):

Look for .RData in your startup folder.  This is automatically loaded when you start up R.